# C++ array wrapper

Tags: c++, arrays, templates

I've wanted a wrapper around arrays, such, it would be stored at the stack - to be not concerned about memory releasing - be initializable via brace lists, and possibly be substitutable in any place of an ordinary array. Then, I've produced the following code. And now am wondering, have I missed something. -- So - is it what I've wanted?

```cpp
template<class T, size_t size>
struct Array
{
    T body[size];

    operator T* () { return body; }
};
```

**Edit:**

I might be imprecise. The wrapper is only for constructional purpose. It shall be used for constructing arrays from brace lists, when being in an initialization list (primarily). Like

```
class A {
    protected: A(int array[])
    ...

class B : public A {
    public: B() : 
        A( (Array<int, 2>) {{ 1, 2 }} )
        ...
```

There was a proposition of a `const` version of the casting operator. - I've been considering this, but am not sure, is it really needed. While casting to `const T[]` is done implicitly through the existing operator, and a constant array can be defined by giving `T = const ...`, is there still a reason?

Comment: You've just described [**`std::array`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)

Comment: Your class should also provide `const`/non-`const` overloads of `operator[N]`.

Comment: @0x499602D2 `[]` should already be handled by the conversion to pointer, but good point about an additional `const` version of that conversion operator.

Answer (score 6):

For a basic example, I don't think there's much you can improve on, except for a few helper functions. In particular, it would be nice to have a method that returns the size:

```
constexpr std::size_t size() const { return size; }
```

---

In addition, here are a few others:

- `const`/non-`const` overloads of `operator[N]`:

  As @ChristianRau stated in the comments, a `operator T*` provides a *non*-`const` version. We can implement the `const` version as such:

  ```
  T const& operator [](std::size_t n) const
  {
      return body[n];
  }
  // similarly for non-const:
  T& operator [](std::size_t n) { return body[n]; }
  ```
- `begin()` and `end()` sequencers (very useful e.g. for the C++11 range-based for):

  ```
  T* begin() { return body; }
  T* end()   { return body + size; }

  // const versions... very much the same
  T const* cbegin() const { return body; }
  T const* cend()   const { return body + size; }
  T const* begin()  const { return cbegin(); }
  T const* end()    const { return cend(); }
  ```
- an `at()` method, which includes bounds checking (as opposed to `operator[]` by convention):

  ```
  T const& at(std::size_t offset) const
  {
      // You should do bounds checking here
      return body[offset];
  }
  // also a non-const version again..
  ```
- It would also be nice to have a constructor that takes an `std::initializer_list<T>` so that you don't have to use the aggregate-initialization:

  ```
  #include <algorithm>
  #include <initializer_list>

  template <typename T, std::size_t N>
  struct Array
  {
      ...
      Array(std::initializer_list<T> const& list)
      {
          std::copy(list.begin(), list.end(), body);
      }
      ...
  };
  ```

  Here is another one suggested by @DyP (initializer list always copies, perfect forwarding tries to avoid that):

  ```
  template <typename T, std::size_t N>
  struct Array
  {
      ...
      template <typename... Args>
      // possibly constexpr
      Array(Args&&... args) : body{ std::forward<Args>(args)... } 
      {}
      ...
  };
  ```

Here is the program in action if you want to see it -- http://ideone.com/Zs27it#view_edit_box

There are others features you can include, but as I said this is a basic example, and you would most likely be better off using something like [**`std::array`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) which has more or less the same methods.

Comment: I think your second comment makes a better answer.  The question *does* describe the desired features.

Comment: Well, maybe I used too big word. The wrapper is not a substitute of array, but a tool purposed purely for construction. - Feathers aren't needed. :)

Comment: Maybe you want return a `T const&` from a `at(std::size_t) const`?

Comment: IMO a ctor with template parameter pack could be better since it can use perfect forwarding (and be `constexpr`).

Comment: What I don't understand also with `std::array` is why `size` is not a static member function.

Comment: @DyP Why should I return `T const&` from `at`? I'm pretty sure it returns a non-const reference in `std::array` and `std:: vector`.

Comment: It does return a `const_reference`: [vector::at](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at); [array::at](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/at)

Comment: Essentially, if you change the content of the container, the observable behaviour changes -> violation of constness IMO

Comment: :) `operator[]` could also return a (const) reference as in the StdLib containers

Comment: Lol the more often I look at it.... `begin` shouldn't be `const` (-> `cbegin`) and if it is, it should also return a `T const*`.. maybe I just edit it and you'll take a look afterwards?

Comment: @Number47 So does my answer help in any way?

Comment: @0x499602D2, I'm grateful for trying, but not really. -- More in the edit.